# Is it possible to add a vertically centered equation number to an align environment consisting of an even set of equations?

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, page-breaking, center, equation-number

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &= b \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= d \\
&= e \\
&= f 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Question: Is there a way of adding a vertically centered, single equation number to an even set of equations within an `align` environment as in the MWE (30 equations)? So far, I always used a `split` environment within `align` to achieve that effect. However, `split` does not allow for automatic pagebreaks. I know this is an old question, but perhaps there are new developments here? Package updates? Or perhaps one could take a look at how `split` calculates the vertical center at which the equation number should be placed, regardless of whether the whole structure is then "linebroken" or not.

Comment: use aligned inside equation, so you get a single number

Comment: **@David**: thanks for the help David, but does `aligned` allow for page breaks? Last time I checked it did not!

Comment: you can't really have vertical centering and line breaking at the same time

Comment: if you really want that use `align` and  `\nonumber`  on all lines except a middle one, but it will confuse the readers if there is a page break

Comment: well, in principle one could calculate the vertical center with the procedure used by `split` and somehow use that information to add an equation number to `align`, thereby ignoring the page break discontinuity, so to say.

Comment: not really. but anyway one or other page will show no number, which is pretty confusing

Comment: hm. I see. A related question: is it possible to move the equation numbers up and down by a certain measure?

Comment: `\raisetag{...}`

Comment: thanks again David! I tried that within an `\align` environment containing several (multiline) equations and several `\nonumber` entries, but it did not change the position of the (only) equation number (that was left). Does `\raisetag` only work if I use `\align*` with addition of a single `tag`? I placed `\raisetag` right at the end of the equation that was numbered (did not work) and then also at the end of the `\align` environment right before the label.

Comment: In such a case I'd split the derivation into two (or three) chunks that can fit in a page and give a number to each one. A thirty line derivation is very boring and reviving the attentions with some comments in the middle will help the reader.

Comment: the outer env needs to be an ams alignment not equation for raisetag, see amsmath manual

Comment: **@egreg**: thanks for the suggestion. I have a number of tensor components and I really need to present them all at once. The only way would be to change my tensor notation, but I don't really want to do that. Anyway, I solved the problem with `\align`. The only minor issue left is perhaps raising the equation number, so that it is positioned at the same place where `split` would have positioned it, but that's a really tiny difference (less than half a centimeter); so, for now it's fine.

Comment: **@David**: alright. I'll check.